# Как через JS определить ширину блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть три блока, которые в рабочей области. 
Один из них текстовый и у него width:auto;
Как определять его ширину и ширину рабочей области через JS?

Comment: $("div").css("width");

Comment: А как потом использовать это значение? к примеру 1000 минус ширина (полученную) и вставить как значение left у другого блока?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант на чистом JS выглядит так:

```
var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
```

Если вы используете библиотеку jQuery, код будет немного проще:

```
var width = $('#foo').width();
```

Comment: А как потом использовать это значение?
к примеру 1000 минус ширина (полученную) и вставить как значение left у другого блока?

Comment: Предположим, id другого блока "bar", а нашего с шириной "foo". Тогда
$("#bar").css('left', 1000 - $("#foo").width());